# Databasing in C++ using fstream library

Tags: c++, fstream

I am making a game, and I am trying to make it write all of the variables to a file, then be able to read it again when you open up the program, therefore saving your progress. Is there any simple way that I could do this? And if it helps, the code can be found at https://github.com/DualSwords/Dual-Swords/blob/dual-swords-post-beta/Dual%20Swords:%20Beta%201.9 Thanks for any assistance you can offer me!

Comment: There are many simple ways that you could do this.   Since you are trying, you could show that attempt directly in this question to make it a little more focused.

Comment: Please post a small sample of what you want to do with your code HERE, not on github. When someone else wants to have the same answer in 6 months time, that code could be VERY different, and thus the answer given here makes no sense to the code posted.

Comment: Smells like you need a database.  There are various size databases from SQLite to MySql and others.  The database will handle the management of your data so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for serializing all your application's object and save/load them to/from a file.

The easiest way is certainly to use the poweverful [boost serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).  It's very easy to use, as shown in its tutorial : it needs just a selialisation function in each object (ok and some gym for collections).